# warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'DATE' to 'int', possible loss of data

Tags: visual-c++, casting

On migrating a VC++ 6.0 developed code to Visual studio 2008, I get this warning. I tried casting using **static_cast** , But even then I'm not able to fix this warning. This is challenging for me to fix.

```
CCandidateDataVector::iterator it;
int iDays;
DATE m_datePolicyStart;
iDays = (*it).m_datePolicyStart; //c4224
```

Thanks for any help to fix this issue.

Comment: What does the line `DATE m_datePolicyStart;` do? Please remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date is a float value, the warning states that you are loosing the decimals

```
double iDays
```

should do it.